# What happens if a VAR model includes a series that is not stationary?

Tags: vector-autoregression, stationarity

What happens if a VAR model includes a series that is not stationary? What effects does it have on its results and impulse response functions? I am writing VAR models and can't seem to figure out why a VAR model need to be stationary.

Comment: While this question is clearly rather sparse, I think it is answerable & the existence of an upvoted answer suggests so as well. I'm voting to leave open.

Answer (score 2):

A modest answer:

[Stability implies stationarity](https://books.google.no/books?id=qJXsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=unstable%20stationary%20process&source=bl&ots=vPRe7sis0Q&sig=YDNtr7afsrKMi-sfSPcYy7XW6hQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwA2oVChMIsPqOw8_0yAIVxJQsCh0ksgtp#v=onepage&q=unstable%20stationary%20process&f=false). So if a model is not stationary, it's not stable, which implies it might eventually blow-up. What would be the interest in models with such characteristic? If a VAR is unstable, it might happen that your impulse-response functions will not converge to zero, implying the shocks would have permanent effects, which is unreasonable in most cases.

Specifically, [[weak] stationarity](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/wiki/Chapter_3.1._Stationarity_and_Stability) implies both the mean and covariance of the process do not change over time, which is a basic assumption for the estimation of the classical VAR model. Finally, for a VAR model to be stationary, it's a necessary condition that all of your series are.

Hint: A way to relax such hypothesis is, for example, switch to cointegration (VECM) models.